# Cowboy rest resource_exists callback

Tags: erlang, cowboy

How does one handle the `resource_exists` callback in cowboy? After all, to find out whether resource exists - I must query (e.g. database) for resource. But then during the `AcceptResource` callback (e.g. `to_html`) I must query for the resource again. Is there any way to prevent this double querying?

Is there any way to preserve that resource for the `AcceptResource` callback, so that I don't have to pull it form database again?

Reading the cowboy docs, there is [flowchart](http://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/1.0/guide/rest_flowcharts/) of how a rest request is handled.
In it, the callback `resource_exists` is called first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `resource_exists` you can add the result of the database query to the `State` variable that `resource_exists` returns.

The state is passed as input to the `AcceptResource` callback where you can use the cached value.

Comment: Right. Makes sense! What is the structure of the state variable? What is it's initial value?

Comment: Oh, got it, it calls `rest_init/2` which must return `{ok, Req, State}`. Source: http://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/1.0/guide/rest_handlers/